# R - Detect end of observations in groups and remove redundant rows

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a data.frame consisting of about 300k rows with 24 rows for each ID - each row representing an hourly observation of that ID. My problem lies in that for some IDs the observation ends before the 24 hours has gone by - yet still have 24 rows with the remaining rows having NA in their 3 observation variables.

In a simplified table would be something like this

```
ID    HOUR    OBS_1    OBS_2    OBS_3    MISC    MISC_2
1      0       29        32       34      19       21
1      1       21        12       NA      19       21
1      2       NA        24       NA      19       21
1      3       NA        NA       NA      19       21
1      4       NA        NA       NA      19       21
2      0       41        16       21      13       24
2      1       NA        NA       NA      13       24
2      2       11        30       41      13       24
2      3       21        NA       NA      13       24
2      4       24        35       21      13       24
2      5       NA        NA       NA      13       24
2      6       NA        NA       NA      13       24
3      0       NA        NA       NA      35       46
3      1       23        34       24      35       46
3      2       NA        26       NA      35       46
3      3       NA        NA       24      35       46
3      4       12        29       42      35       46
3      5       NA        NA       NA      35       46
3      6       NA        NA       NA      35       46
```

In the table, each ID would represent a scenario that should be handled appropriately:

- **ID 1**: Ordinary with observations starting from hour 0 and observation ending at hour 3 - and thus row with hour 3 and 4 for that group should be removed
- **ID 2**: Has an hour (1) where all three observation variables are set at NA, but observation is resumed and ends at hour 5 - and thus row 2 should be kept (due to faulty registration and not end of observation) and rows with hour 5 and 6 should be removed.
- **ID 3**: Starts out with an row with NA in all three observation variables, but observation begins then next hour and ends at hour 5. This is akin to the scenario for ID 2, but this time occurring at the very start (instead of in the middle of the observations). However, this still represent a faulty registration and should be kept and rows from hour 5 and 6 in this group should be removed.

Conceptually, I would think a possible solution would be do a group_by ID and then for R to go through the rows in a group in reverse (from bottom and up) until it encounters a row where "OBS_1", "OBS_2" and "OBS_3" are not all NA and remove the rows examined before reaching to this row and then move on to examine the next group.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your MISC and MISC_2 values are consistent for each ID, you could 
filter all rows that have na values then fill back in the missing data with `complete` and `fill`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% filter(!(is.na(OBS_1)&is.na(OBS_2)&is.na(OBS_3))) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  complete(HOUR=0:max(HOUR)) %>%
  fill(MISC,MISC_2) %>% fill(MISC,MISC_2,.direction = "up")


# A tibble: 13 x 7
# Groups:   ID [3]
#       ID  HOUR OBS_1 OBS_2 OBS_3  MISC MISC_2
#    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>  <int>
#  1     1     0    29    32    34    19     21
#  2     1     1    21    12    NA    19     21
#  3     1     2    NA    24    NA    19     21
#  4     2     0    41    16    21    13     24
#  5     2     1    NA    NA    NA    13     24
#  6     2     2    11    30    41    13     24
#  7     2     3    21    NA    NA    13     24
#  8     2     4    24    35    21    13     24
#  9     3     0    NA    NA    NA    35     46
# 10     3     1    23    34    24    35     46
# 11     3     2    NA    26    NA    35     46
# 12     3     3    NA    NA    24    35     46
# 13     3     4    12    29    42    35     46
```

Comment: MISC and MISC_2 should have the same value throughout all 24 rows for each group - also in the sense that if one of them is NA then the other would be too and they would be NA throughout all 24 rows in that group. Two follow-up questions - 1. How would the code fare if MISC and MISC_2 are NA? It seems to still work in the simplified table, but curious if it will affect the real data.frame. 2. How will it fare with groups akin to ID 2, but instead with multiple rows where OBS_1, OBS_2 and OBS_3 are NA spread between rows with observations until the real end occurs?

Comment: 1. It defaults to NA so I imagine it would be fine. 2. shouldnt matter because the complete will add values from 0 to the maximum or "real end".  I'd check out the `tidyr` documentation if you're curious about how anything works.

Answer (score 0):

This filters only the missing values if the no observation for the day are existing after this and keeps all missing observations that do not indicate the end of the observations for the day. These also allow for your other variables to vary during the day because it just removes them if the end of observations is reached.

```
 df %>% arrange(rev(as.numeric(rownames(.)))) %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>%
   mutate(rowNum = 1:n(),
          naObs = cumsum((is.na(OBS_1) & is.na(OBS_2) & is.na(OBS_3))), 
          missingBlock = naObs != rowNum) %>%
   slice(min(which(missingBlock)):n()) %>%
   ungroup() %>%
   arrange(rev(as.numeric(rownames(.)))) %>%
   select(-rowNum, -naObs, -missingBlock)
```